# Transforming generator to Pandas Dataframe: very high memory consumption

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a BSON file of size ~2GB and transforming it into a dataframe for processing. The problem is, the process of loading it into a dataframe takes up to 20GB of RAM.

Loading the data:

```py
with open(os.path.join(DATA_DIR, filename), 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
    data = bson.decode_iter(data) # produces a generator of dictionaries
    print(f'memory consumption: {process.memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2} MB')
```

1. I don't get how a ~2GB file can bloat up to 20GB. I've tried passing the generator directly into the dataframe, and I still get the same memory consumption.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data) # passing in the generator directly yields ~20GB RAM consumption
```

2. Tried doing it by chunks. Implementation as below, but no change in consumption. I've combined both `del` and `gc.collect()` but neither seems to make any difference to the memory consumption.

```py
def get_chunks(d, chunksize=500000):
    while True:
        vals = []
        for i in range(chunksize):
            try:
                vals.append(next(d))
            except StopIteration:
                break
        yield vals
```

```py
main_df = pd.DataFrame()
chunk = next(get_chunks(data)) # initialise the first chunk
i = 1
while len(chunk) != 0:
    print(f'Chunk number: {i}')
    print(f'memory consumption: {process.memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2} MB')
    print(f'chunk length: {len(chunk)}')

    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(chunk)
    del chunk
    main_df = pd.concat([main_df, temp_df], axis=0)
    print(f'memory consumption: {process.memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2} MB')
    print('------')
    del temp_df
    gc.collect()
    chunk = next(get_chunks(data))
    i += 1
```

Would appreciate if someone can explain (i) what is wrong with these approaches and why/how memory consumption gets bloated up to 10x. What am I doing wrong? (ii) Is there an alternate approach to loading the generator into the dataframe that consumes reasonable amounts of memory (i.e. *not* 10x more!).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. On the `file.read` - at most, that only loads 2GB of memory. That doesn't explain the 10x bloat. On the `pd.concat` - that's fair, but in the first method, I've shown passing in the generator as-is into the DataFrame constructor still yields a 10x bloat. I'll look more into the quadratic copying, and look for a better way. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Read through the link you provided: in the comments, it was mentioned quadratic copying affects the speed, not the memory.